# Что на ваш взляд оптимальней установить?

Tags: веб-программирование

Не можем определиться с платформой сайта. Что на ваш взгляд оптимальней установить? По мимо надёжности учитывайте пожалуйста сложность и скорость разработки модулей. Django(python) или modx(php).

Comment: MODx - это CMS, Django - полноценный фреймворк. Что Вы хотите сделать? Почему скажем не Yii, Kohana, Lavarel vs Django?

Comment: MODx это как раз таки фреймворк http://modx.com/why-modx/applications/content-management-framework/

Comment: да и джанга с ее автоматической админкой и автоматическим всем тоже не чистый фреймворк

Comment: Можно сравнивать с Wordpress. Но это все же не полноценный фреймфорк как тот же Yii, Symphony, или Lavarel и др.

Comment: @jack-out, а почему только Django и MODx. А в сторону рельсов не смотрели? Хотя в любом случае, нужен толковый разработчик. А технологию он и сам выберет, если соображает.

Comment: Я думаю пусть выбирает разработчик. Если вы сами разработчик, то выбирайте то, с чем опыта больше, где удобнее по вашему мнению, где вы считаете будет надежнее лучше и быстрее. Если ни там ни там не работали - то получиться первый блин com-ом.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, конечно, задан конгениально, но:

- PHP стоит ВЕЗДЕ, питон - нет (на самом деле тоже практически везде, просто не на каждом хостинге им дают пользоваться) (чо не мешает взять впс)
- PHP - самый распространенный язык, найти девелопера не проблема, стоит он поменьше, чем питон

В то же время

- Предыдущий пункт одновременно говорит о том, что половина знающих PHP - школьники, а в случае с питоном вероятность получить плохой код несколько меньше (хотя он тоже достаточно популярен для появления *необъяснимых* строк в коде)
- Питон будет побыстрее, и что касается надежности, то modx и джанга условно одинаковы (т.е. я не слышал в последнее время историй о взломе одного или другого), но вот PHP - это срамный ад, я недавно видел статью, где ломанули форум из-за того, что хеш md5 получилось успешно сравнить с (!) нулем.
- Никто не мешает взять ВПС и резвиться там с любыми языками
- Питоновые разработчики смогут накрутить простенький демон, а пхпшники - нет. Точнее, смогут, но вам им лучше не пользоваться.

Ну и последнее

- Скорость разработки зависит исключительно от конкретного разработчика. Я, например, медленное чмо.
- Сложность, в общем-то, туда же - в джанге много сделано для "быстрого старта", но любой проект все равно упирается в сам язык, потому что как только начинается что-то серьезное, там уже нет пространства для "общих решений", которые включены в фреймворк. Джанга впереди, но при серьезном проекте силы скорее всего уравняются.

Comment: у нас будет свой vps

Answer (score 1):

Для разработки не стандартного проекта я бы воспользовался - kohana, для магазина - opencart, для блога - wordpress